# azure data factory lookup activity - parameterize sql query

Tags: azure-data-factory

How do I parameterize the where condition in a lookup activity query in azure data factory? I have created a pipeline parameter and tried to pass it to the lookup activity query as given below.

select max(dt) as dt from tab1 where col='@pipeline.parameters.parama1'

I have tried with quotes, without quotes, curly brackets, but still not firing. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Official doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions

*Expressions can also appear inside strings, using a feature called string interpolation where expressions are wrapped in @{ ... }.*

Taking this into consideration, this may work for you:

```
select max(dt) as dt from tab1 where col=@{pipeline().parameters.param}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank You Martin, It was helpful. Required to add quotes before and after the parameter.                                                                                                                       select max(dt) as dt from tab1 where col='@{pipeline().parameters.param}'

Comment: Glad to be of help! The quotes make sense because it says inside strings!